# I can know if audio is playing

Tags: cordova, plugins

I am using the cordova-plugin-media plug-in in an audio project. I wanted to ask if there is a way to know if the audio is playing or if it has started playing

Answer (score 0):

You can check the playing position of `Media` using

```
var sound = new Media(...);

setInterval(() => {console.log(sound._position);}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks Erik for the answer but what has to go is not an audio file but a stream

Comment: You should post some code then, are you sure you are referring to the right plugin?